# sass import node_modules script

Tags: npm, sass, gulp

I'm new to gulp, susy, sass, and have been looking for a solution to my following problem but haven't been successful in finding one.

```
@import 'susy';
@import 'breakpoint-sass';
```

does not work, but

```
@import "../node_modules/modularscale-sass/stylesheets/_modular-scale.scss";
@import "../node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss";
```

works. But it's not the right way isn't it?
I've also tried, `sudo npm install breakpoint-sass --save-dev` but still didn't work.

My project looks like

```
.
├── assets
│   ├── atoms
│   │   └── _test.scss
│   └── style.scss
├── dist
│   └── style.css
├── gulpfile.js
└── package.json
```

and this is my gulp file:

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
      browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
      reload = browserSync.reload,
      autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
      sass = require('gulp-sass')
      imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
      uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
      plumber = require('gulp-plumber');



gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./assets/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({
          outputStyle: 'compressed',
          includePaths: ['node_modules/susy/sass']
      }).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

and this is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.6",
    "breakpoint-sass": "^2.7.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "modularscale-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "susy": "^2.2.12"
  }
}
```

I hope you could help me out.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the paths to the `includePaths` parameter in your `sass` task.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./assets/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({
          outputStyle: 'compressed',
          includePaths: [
            'node_modules/susy/sass',
            'node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets'
          ]
      }).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

In fact you had that already for susy just not breakpoint-sass. You can't import `breakpoint-sass` either, it has to be just `breakpoint`:

```
@import 'susy';
@import 'breakpoint';
```

That's because you want to import the file called `node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss`. Your import would try and find `node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint-sass.scss` which doesn't exist.

For reference, the steps for installing and using a SASS library are:

1. Install the library with npm.
2. Find the library in `node_modules/`. Expand it, and find the file you want to `@import`. In this case it's `_breakpoint.scss`.
3. Add the path to the directory the file from step 3 lives in to `includePaths`.
4. Add the import to your own SASS source.

Or you can just keep the full `@import` in your code if you want. Or just include node_modules and then import e.g. `susy/sass/susy` and `breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint`. It's up to you really.